# Drupal 7: Server redirected you too many times

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-feeds

I used the `Feeds` module to import users on my application, along with a field for the email address (which was unique) and a password. The user data was imported successfully for all users. However, when I try to login through an imported user's login credentials, I encounter the following error:

```
Server redirected you too many times.
ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS
```

I tried logging in from different browsers but that's didn't seem to resolve the issue either. What seems to be wrong here?

PS: I have tried clearing caches and deleting my browser's cookies as well, but that didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: Probably 2 pages redirection one to another and you get in infinite loop.

Comment: I got this problem following an new drupal 7.43 setup, uploading a template and trying to run install.php